# Padding or margin issue?

Tags: html, css

I really like how http://designmodo.com/ has simulated 3D borders on their navigation, so I'm trying to recreate that in my site. However, on my site, border-right and border-left in the `nav` are not touching each other, but instead separated by a small space. How can I fix this?

Thank you for your time.

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/1140.css">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <!-- Logo goes here -->
        <div class="container12">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Departments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headFix"></div>
    <div class="info">

    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container12">

        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS:

```
.head { /* preffered color is blackish:#2E3234 or  blue:#245789*/
    display: block;
    clear: none;
    background-color: #446CB3;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav a:link, nav a:visited {
    border-left: 1px solid #587BBA;
    border-right: 1px solid #3D61A1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E4EBF0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 23px;
    padding: 26px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -o-transition: .2s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition:.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out; 
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #446CB3;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JmNJ9/)

Comment: Why are u using two borders then? Use just 1.

Comment: Have either of our answers fixed the issues you are having, or is there something else we can help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's Going On

When you use `display:inline-block`, you tell an element to behave like a `block` element in terms of it's design, and like an `inline` element in terms of placement. The spacing between the elements falls under the placement, or the `inline` part of this.

There is an odd quirk with CSS and `inline-block` elements, where upon if you have linebreaks between elements in the HTML code file, you will see a space between them in the results. You have a couple ways to address this.

---

## Method 1 - Remove the linebreaks in HTML File

Leave your CSS as it is, and change the HTML file. Makes for ugly HTML though.

#### Original HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Departments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
<li><a href="#">More</a></li>
```

#### New HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Departments</a></li><li><a href="#">Library</a></li><li><a href="#">More</a></li>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JmNJ9/2/)

#### Result

[image]

---

## Method 2 - Use `Float` Instead of `Inline-Block`

You can keep your HTML structure as it is, and use `float:left` to make things line up horizontally.

#### Original CSS:

```
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

#### New CSS:

```
nav li {
    float:left;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JmNJ9/3/)

#### Result

[image]

---

## Borders On Outside

If you've noticed, both methods don't have a double border on the outside. We can add this by giving the containing `ul` borders that are opposite colors as the `li`s have. However, if we use Method 2, we'll have to set that `ul` to `display:inline-block` to bring the borders down.

Use this WITH (IN ADDITION TO) Method 2 or 1.

#### Original CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

#### New CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #3D61A1;
    border-right: 1px solid #587BBA;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JmNJ9/1/)

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
nav li {
  float: left;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rHjwt/)

Comment: "but on my site, border-right and border-left in the nav are not next to each other. How can I fix this?" How will floating elements to left fix it? Edit: Although the result is achieved.

Comment: Consider adding a bit of an explanation to short code answers like this. Otherwise, nice answer!